# print from python file to kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Let say I have a python scripts name myscript.py

```
import time
a = 0

def printing():
   global a
   a +=1
   print(" something = ", a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   while True:
      time.sleep(1)
      printing()
```

If i run this script in python it gonna out put something like this:

```
something = 1
something = 2 
something = 3 
...
```

I looking for away that if i press a start button in kivy it start the myscript.py and print out the message above in kivy GUI. If i press stop button it stop the myscript.py

something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcYlK.png)

Comment: Do you want the script output to appear in the terminal, as it does in your code above, or are you asking how to get it to appear inside a Kivy GUI?

Comment: Hi John, im looking for it to appear in kivy GUI. I have edit the question to make it more clear. Sorry about the unclear question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another possible answer:

```
import time
from functools import partial
from threading import Thread

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

from myscript import printing

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    run_script = False

    def run_script_in_thread(self):
        self.the_thread = Thread(target=self.script, daemon=True).start()

    def script(self):
        self.run_script = True
        f = io.StringIO()
        with redirect_stdout(f):
            while self.run_script:
                time.sleep(1)
                printing()
                out = f.getvalue()
                Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.set_label, out), -1)

    def set_label(self, value, dt):
        self.ids.the_output.text = value

    def stop_script(self):
        self.run_script = False

theRoot = Builder.load_string('''
MyLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        id: the_output
    Button:
        text: 'Start'
        on_release: root.run_script_in_thread()
    Button:
        text: 'Stop'
        on_release: root.stop_script()

''')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return theRoot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This uses `redirect_stdout` to capture the output from `printing()`, which is imported using `from myscript import printing`. Note that your `while` loop cannot be used because it is protected by `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

If you need to run the script, including the `while` loop, you could use a separate `Process` to run it and a `Pipe` to capture the output.